# How to read values from array of objects in appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, arrays, object, configuration, appsettings

My appsettings json file

```
       {
         "StudentBirthdays": [
                { "Anne": "01/11/2000"},
                { "Peter": "29/07/2001"},
                { "Jane": "15/10/2001"},
                { "John": "Not Mentioned"}
            ]
        }
```

I have a seperate config class.

```
public string GetConfigValue(string key)
{
    var value = _configuration["AppSettings:" + key];
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Convert.ToString(value) : string.Empty;
}
```

What I  have tried is,

```
 list= _configHelper.GetConfigValue("StudentBirthdays");
```

For the above I dont get the values.

How can I read the values(I want to read the name of the student and his birthday **seperatly**).

Any help is apreciated

Comment: Wha  the value of list you get?

Comment: I'd suggest using `.GetSection` and iterate through it.

Comment: @Serge I dont get any values for list.(null)

Comment: @Llama you mean "_configHelper.GetSection("StudentBirthdays"); " ,after implementing a seperate method to GetSection in config class ?

Comment: I mean `_configuration.GetSection`, and yes, probably something like that in the `_configHelper` class to provide access to it.

Comment: @Llama Tried it.But still it returns a null value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the birthdays using the following code:

```
// get the section that holds the birthdays
var studentBirthdaysSection = _configuration.GetSection("StudentBirthdays");

// iterate through each child object of StudentBirthdays
foreach (var studentBirthdayObject in studentBirthdaysSection.GetChildren())
{
    // your format is a bit weird here where each birthday is a key:value pair,
    // rather than something like { "name": "Anne", "birthday": "01/11/2000" }
    // so we need to get the children and take the first one
    var kv = studentBirthdayObject.GetChildren().First();
    string studentName = kv.Key;
    string studentBirthday = kv.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", studentName, studentBirthday);
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cWsh46)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using System.Linq;

public List<Student> GetStudentsFromConfig()
{
    return  _configuration
    .GetSection("StudentBirthdays")
    .Get<Dictionary<string, string>[]>()
    .SelectMany(i => i)
    .Select(ie => new Student {Name=ie.Key, DOB=ie.Value})
    .ToList();
}
```

test

```
items= _configHelper.GetStudentsFromConfig();

foreach (var item in items) Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name} , DOB: {item.DOB} ");
```

result

```
Name: Anne , DOB: 01/11/2000 
Name: Peter , DOB: 29/07/2001 
Name: Jane , DOB: 15/10/2001 
Name: John , DOB: Not Mentioned
```

class

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have already implemeted model classes controlleres and everything.And it get value from other keys.As this student birthdays consist an array i find it difficult.Is there a way that i can accomplish this by using same set of file structure that i have created.because what i am trying to do is getting the name and birthday from from db and check whether it is similar to the data in the appsettings or not.

Comment: @rissa You should mention it in your question. I updated my answer. You can check again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Create Model/Class like below:

```
public class StudentBirthday
{
   String Name,
   String Birthday
}
```

Then access values like this :

```
List<StudentBirthday StudentBirthdays = 
   _config.GetSection("Main:StudentBirthdays").Get<List<StudentBirthday();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).